# Copy range of values between workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy either single cells values or rows of cells from a source workbook to a target workbook.

The user will have three workbooks open:

1. Dashboard workbook
2. Source workbook
3. Target workbook

The sub reads the user input in Dashboard workbook, which will look like the following:

```
Source cells    Target cells    Cell/Row
G28             H30             Cell
G29             H31             Row
```

The sub is then supposed to look up cell G28 in Source workbook and copy that into H30 in Target workbook. Likewise the sub is supposed to look up cell G29 in Source workbook and copy that cell and everything to the right into H31 in Target workbook.

I managed to copy single cell values. I have not been able to implement the functionality for the row type input.

I indicated below where the error is.

```
Sub transferSub()

Dim wbMain As Workbook: Set wbMain = ThisWorkbook
Dim wbMainDashboard As Worksheet: Set wbMainDashboard = wbMain.Worksheets("Dashboard")

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'Definition of file path for source and target workbooks
sourceModel = wbMainDashboard.Range("FILE_SOURCE") 'Pull from dashboard input
targetModel = wbMainDashboard.Range("FILE_TARGET") 'Pull from dashboard input

'Source and target workbooks
Dim wbSource As Workbook: Set wbSource = Workbooks(sourceModel) 'Workbook already open
Dim wbTarget As Workbook: Set wbTarget = Workbooks(targetModel) 'Workbook already open

'Source and target worksheet
Dim wskpInput_source As Worksheet: Set wskpInput_source = wbSource.Worksheets("INPUT (kp)")
Dim wsSCEInput_source As Worksheet: Set wsSCEInput_source = wbSource.Worksheets("INPUT (SCE)")
'Source and target worksheet
Dim wskpInput_target As Worksheet: Set wskpInput_target = wbTarget.Worksheets("INPUT (kp)")
Dim wsSCEInput_target As Worksheet: Set wsSCEInput_target = wbTarget.Worksheets("INPUT (SCE)")

'Procedures
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = wbMainDashboard.Range("Dashboard!E9:E15")
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
    cell_source = rng.Cells(i, 1)
    cell_target = rng.Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1)
    cell_cellrow = rng.Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 3)

    If cell_cellrow = "Cell" Then 'If cell then copy paste value in that cell
        wskpInput_target.Range(cell_target) = wskpInput_source.Range(cell_source).Value
    ElseIf cell_cellrow = "Row" Then 'If row then copy and paste the row of cells
        wskpInput_source.Range(cell_source, cell_source.End(xlToRight)).Copy _
            wskpInput_target.Range(cell_target)  '---NEED HELP WITH THIS PART---
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Note - best practice is to declare all variables. You have a few that are not. Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module. It looks like `cell_source` is a `String` - and you can't call `.End` on a `String` - i.e. `cell_source.End(xlToRight)`.

Comment: If `cell_source` (etc) are strings (addresses) then you probably need `range(cell_source).End(xlToRight)`.

Comment: ^ and make sure that you qualify the worksheet too.

Comment: FYI - `wbMainDashboard.Range("Dashboard!E9:E15")` is a little redundant. Since you already declared `wbMainDashboard` and are correctly qualifying the `Range()` with that worksheet, you could just do `wbMainDashboard.Range("E9:E15")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the `Range` object can either get `Cells` as arguments or a `String` (details [here](https://wellsr.com/vba/excel/vba-range-object/)).

Hard-coding the range with a string argument would look like this:

```
wskpInput_source.Range("G28:L28").Copy _ 
destination:=wskpInput_target.Range(cell_target)
```

but since you already have a variable containing the first cell ("G28") in the row, we only need to find the last cell, you can get it with a `Function` like the following:

```
Function GetLastCellInRow(sheetName As String, firstCell As String) As String

   Sheets(sheetName).Range(firstCell).End(xlToRight).Select
   GetLastCellInRow = ActiveCell.Address

End Function
```

and this is how you call it

```
'MySheet is the source sheet, so you need to modify that
cell_source_last = GetLastCellInRow(MySheet.Name, cell_source)
```

And putting all together:

```
cell_source = rng.Cells(i, 1)
cell_target = rng.Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 1)
cell_cellrow = rng.Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 3)
'MySheet is the source sheet, so you need to modify that
cell_source_last = GetLastCellInRow(MySheet.Name, cell_source)

If cell_cellrow = "Cell" Then 'If cell then copy paste value in that cell
    wskpInput_target.Range(cell_target) = wskpInput_source.Range(cell_source).Value
ElseIf cell_cellrow = "Row" Then 'If row then copy and paste the row of cells
    wskpInput_source.Range(cell_source & ":" & cell_source_last).Copy _
        Destination:=wskpInput_target.Range(cell_target)
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much for assisting me on this. Your solutions seems to be exactly what I am looking for but I am getting a "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" error when I run the GetLastCellInRow function. Do you know why this is? I have all workbooks open: (i) dashboard, (ii) Source, and (iii) Target. My variable definitions of these workbooks (and sheets) are also working but I think the Sheets(wsKpInput_source).Range(firstcell).End(xlToRight).Select for some reason won't work with the source workbook?

Comment: well, the method `Sheets()` recieves either an integer or a string as parameters, and you are giving the variable `wsKpInput_source` wich is apparently a `Worksheet`.
try changing the line `Sheets(wsKpInput_source).Range(firstcell).End(xlToRight).Select` to-> `wsKpInput_source.Range(firstcell).End(xlToRight).Select`

Comment: can you show me how are you calling the function `GetLastCellInRow()`?

Comment: I am calling it exactly as you showed in your example. However, I have discovered that when I have the Source workbook open and in front of the Dashboard and Target workbooks then everything works fine. It is only when the Source workbook is in the back that I get a subscript out of range error. I have tried to implement a "wsKpInput_Source.Activate before the .Select, but this had no effect. Do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: I have tried to add wbSource As String in the Function GetLastCellInRow and use wbSource.Name in order to specify the workbook -> Workbooks(wbSource).Sheets(wsKpInput_source).Range(firstcell).End(xlToRight).Select but this leads to a 1004 error - Select method of range class failed.

Comment: you dont need to create an additional String, the object Worksheet already has a property to return it's name as a string, you can find the details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.name).